# WebdriverIO/Cucumber-js/SauceLabs: Set up a hook to send pass/fail of build

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs, saucelabs

I have a couple of feature files with step definitions, also I've connected to SauceLabs and my builds are running, but I can't figure out how to properly send pass or fail of builds.

Curently I have the following hooks setup in `wdio.conf.js`

```

```
  afterTest: function afterTest(test) {
    browser.deleteCookie();
    browser.localStorage('DELETE');
    browser.end();
  },
  before() {
    global.expect = require('jest-matchers');
    global.browser.execute(`sauce:job-name=End-to-End tests at ` + `${jobName}`);
  },
  after() {
    global.browser.execute('sauce:job-result=passed');
  }
```

```
Also found out that there are also specific hooks for cucumber like `afterScenario`, `afterFeature` etc. but still with those I was not able to solve the issue.

To sum up: I need to send that the job passed when it passed and when one of the scenarios at least failed I need to send that the job failed.

Comment: You might find these useful https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Node.js+Test+Setup+Example#Node.jsTestSetupExample-ReportingonTestResults and https://www.npmjs.com/package/saucelabs

Comment: @tehbeardedone thanks, but I can't figure out how to determine if the scenario failed or not so that I can create an if/else for when it fails to update the job.

Comment: I've added an answer with an example that should work. The `test` object passed into the `afterTest` function has several properties that you will find useful. Try logging it to the console to see what all is available to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `passed` property on the `test` object passed into the `afterTest` function. You can just use it like this...

```
//define this stuff at the top of your config
var SauceLabs = require('saucelabs');

var myAccount = new SauceLabs({
  username: "your-sauce-username",
  password: "your-sauce-api-key"
});

....

//then use it like this
afterTest: function(test) {
    saucelabs.updateJob(browser.session().sessionId, {
      name: test.title,
      passed: test.passed
    }, done);
  });
}
```